# ftp mget does not show successful completion

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I was using ftp and successfully connecting to the host.
Then I do

```
 mget test.tar.gz
```

Even though it successfully test.tar.gz, I have to check the size of the file manually with ls -l command in the other terminal. Is there any way that mget or some other command will indicate to me that the transfer of the file is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on the implementation of the FTP server, but in most cases you should receive something like

```
250 transfer complete.
```

`250` basically is the return code for *Requested file action okay, completed*. while the text messages differ sometimes between servers.

In order to make sure you see all the return codes, run your ftp with `-v`, which enables verbose mode. This forces `ftp` (and many other linux ftp clients I know of) to show all responses from the remote server, as well as report on data transfer statistics.

A list of most server return codes can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes).